# Remove the quote in the number

Tags: php

This is really simple but I don't know how and I really need a quick answer.

So here's my output.

> [[['Dannish','24'],['Enterprise','34']]]

And I want it to become

> [[['Dannish',24],['Enterprise',34]]]

Or just simply remove the quote from the numbers. And keep the numbers.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how are you creating that data? using `json_encode()`? If so you can cast those numbers to integer first by using `(int)`.

Comment: you want change a string to a number. this is easy (integer)$value

Comment: @mauris some data are created manually like the enterprise that I need a sa ] in the end. anyway, i already made my fixed but its the lazy way.

its  $return = str_replace(',\'', ', ', $return);
  $return = str_replace('\']', ']', $return);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "[[['Dannish','24'],['Enterprise','34']]] ";
$pattern = "#'(\d+)'#";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a string you are building you can cast it to an integer

```
(int)$value;
```

How are you building this string? Do you have any code?

Comment: Don't you mean `(int)$value`?

Comment: Yes... whoops, let's just ignore that!